# How do I optimize data import into SQL Server with 100000 records with 100s of concurrent users

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlbulkcopy

I am using Visual Studio web application using ASP.NET MVC & C#. I have an Excel file of more than 100000 records for import into SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have used `SqlBulkCopy` with ado.net `DataTable` to copy data to a table (`Table1`).

Then validating and processing data and marking with valid/invalid.

Then adding and updating records to 3 tables (`Table2`, `Table3` and `Table4`) from `Table1` using a stored procedure.

`Table4` contains 2 triggers and it is using cursor to update several records related to it inside `Table4` and another table (`Table2`).

When testing it is taking 1 minute for 10000 records from my local machine with debug mode.

If 10 or 100 users imports at same time, would it support?

Is there any better process to improve and supports for many concurrent users?

My computer configuration:

- Windows 10 64Bit
- AMD FX QuardCore 3.6 GHz processor
- 8GB RAM
- Excel file contains 50 columns
- BulkCopy takes 2 - 3 seconds
- Stored procedure takes 30 seconds to 2 minutes

When I test it with 5 concurrent user, 2 or 3 process successfully executed and I get this error:

> Transaction (Process ID 66) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Comment: It seems your question is about performance and concurrency of the stored procedure. Add the DDL (including indexes) as well as proc and trigger code to your question. Generally, cursors are bad for performance and it might be better to move the trigger code to the proc.

Comment: There are many pieces in your import. Work out which part is taking the longest. I am always suspicious of cursors.

Comment: I have tried disabling triggers, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look & try Zzz Project, you can bulk insert a million records in few seconds.
It supports Entity Framework, Dapper.
[ZZZProject](http://www.zzzprojects.com/)

Comment: How would introducing EF into the mix make this run any faster?

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you disable (or maybe, drop and re-create later) indexes during import? Indexes fasten the select but slow down Insert and update for large tables? Use MERGE instead of INSERT and UPDATE.
2. Find an alternative for cursor (like CTE or while loop or MERGE statement) or use FAST_FORWARD cursor, if not already using.
3. How are you validating data. Is that step fast enough?
4. Do you need triggers during Bulk processing. Are these tables being used from somewhere. Code of trigger which will execute per row, can you execute that in a batch in bulk import process. There is an option to DISABLE triggers in Sql. Do check if that suits your purpose.
5. SSIS packages also can import data and do such stuff.
6. You can create table2_temp, table3_temp,table4_temp (may be per user dynamically and drop them later). Do your processing separately and MERGE into main table2, table3, table4, if the triggers in table4 do not work on pre-existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Insert or import this records to new or temporary tables and later or copy/move to destination tables.

Comment: As I mentioned, Table1 is my temp table. I copied (bulk copy) data into Table1, then adding or updating data to destination table (Table2, Table3 and Table4)

Comment: Add nolock to queries, change transcatioion isolation level, use precomiled code dll, disable triggers on tables.

Answer (score 0):

Add no lock to queries so you will not block operations.